# How to use lambda to initialize ThreadFactory with named Thread

Tags: java

With method reference, I could create a ThreadFactory instance with following code:

```
ThreadFactory factory = Thread::new;
```

From ThreadFactory's interface definition, `Thread::new` will be interpreted as constructor with signature `public Thread(Runnable target)`

Thread also has another overloaded constructor `public Thread(Runnable target, String name)`,

I would ask how to use this constructor and method reference/lambda to construct ThreadFactory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ThreadFactory` has a single abstract method, `Thread newThread(Runnable)`, so we need a lambda that takes a single `Runnable` and returns a thread. You want to use a method (constructor) that takes two parameters and turn it into a method that only needs one of those parameters.

Creating a function that "reduces" the number of inputs is called [*currying*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), and using it is [*partial application*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application). In this case, you want to *partially apply* your thread name ahead of time. With a lambda, you can do this:

```
String name = "thread-name";
ThreadFactory factory = runnable -> new Thread(runnable, name);
// -> captures the value in "name"
```

Note that this will produce *the exact same thread name* every time it's called, so you don't want to use this in a case where it will be used repeatedly.

Some libraries, [such as Vavr](https://static.javadoc.io/io.vavr/vavr/0.10.1/io/vavr/Function2.html#apply-T1-), have built-in support for taking a function with N parameters and fixing one, but it isn't built into the JDK, and fixing a non-first parameter usually requires a custom lambda anyway.

Comment: Thanks @chrylis for the helpful answer!